# Can anyone give me a solution to my task with Generics and Comparable interface?

Tags: java, comparable

I wrote half of it but cannot get it 100% correct. Can anyone help me with it?

Here is my problem:

Write a parameterized class Triple that represents a trio of some type (eg, the Three of String, the Integer , etc.). For Triple class define:

-getElement method that receives an integer number (1,2 or 3) and returns the corresponding member. In the case of an illegal argument, throw an IllegalArgumentExpression exception
-setElement that receives two arguments: an integer number (1, 2 or 3) and the value to be placed as a member of the three in the corresponding position (eg, setElement(2,3) sets 3 to y value of trio) 
-a constructor with 3 arguments that set the initial values of the Triple

Then you should write the ComparableTriple class, which represents the triplet.  Members of triplet must be comparable (implement Comparable interface). Then expand the ComparableTriple class to implement the Comparable interface, so that triplets can be comparable by positions. For example ,(2,6,1) is in the rank before (3,4,5) but behind (2,6, -4). Same template can be applied to String etc.

Example of main code:

Triple t1 = new ComparableTriple<>(2, 6, 1);
int x = t1.compareTo(t1); // should be 0

```java
//Triple class I wrote 

public class Triple<T> {
    T x, y, z;

    public Triple(T x, T y, T z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public T getElement(int position) {
        if (position == 1) {
            return x;
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return y;
        } else if (position == 3) {
            return z;
        } else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    public void setElement(int position, T value) {
        if (position == 1) {
            x = value;
        } else if (position == 2) {
            y = value;
        } else if (position == 3) {
            z = value;
        } else throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
}
```

I tried writing ComparableTriple overriding CompareTo method but couldn't find the exact solution.
It's not so complicated but I'm new to Generics and can't figure some things out.
Can anyone help me about the rest of code?

Comment: *"I tried writing ComparableTriple"* Show us your attempt.

Comment: I tried it with second method but apparently evaluator won't work with arrays in some occasions.
Sorry, code is too long so I will just print screen it:
http://prntscr.com/ndx885
http://prntscr.com/ndx83f

Comment: No idea what that comment even means, and you still haven't edited the question and added the code with your attempt at implementing the `ComparableTriple` class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to stackoverflow, need to figure some things out first.

Comment: Then delete the question and ask a new one when you have a complete question.

Comment: No hard feelings but I don't see your point here. Would be great if you could just stop commenting and maybe someone will help me. I think my question is on point, but I don't see your point in making this discussion here.

Comment: The point is that we're not going to write your code for you. *Show* your attempt at implementing `ComparableTriple`, explain what is stopping you, and we will help. You said you tried, but until you show us, we don't believe you. There are too many people claiming that without doing so, hoping that we do their work for them. Prove to us that you're not one of them, and we'll be happy to help. Don't prove it, and we'll ignore your request to do your homework for you. It's also easier to guide you, when we can see where you're stuck. Right now, question is too broad.

Comment: Lol, having a great reputation doesn't make you a badass so you can act like that. I showed you code written using arrays and even that code doesn't work. I'm not that great in generics yet since I've been using them for a week now. So I tried writing Triple using x,y,z variables but still cannot to solve this out.
Thanks for help, you are an amazing person and developer, I came here, just copied task and I'm just waiting for someone to solve it for me. Great point here. Wish you all the best.

Comment: *"I showed you code written using arrays"* I see no code using arrays. --- *" I tried writing Triple using x,y,z variables"* I see that code and it looks good. I see no problem there, and you didn't say you had one, so good. --- I'm no acting like a badass. I'm simply explaining that you should improve your question, and you'll be more likely to get help. If you had shown your attempt at writing the `ComparableTriple` class, I would have helped too. But if you don't want help, don't improve the question. But then again, why did you ask in the first place?

Comment: I showed it in my answer, like 25mins ago where I said the code is too long but I'll print screen it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Triple<T> implements Comparable<Triple<T>> {
  ... your code here
// functional interface Comparable will force you to override the method
}
```

But you may want to have some kind of superclass that T extends so you can access fields for the compare.

Example:

```
public class Triple<T extends Number> implements Comparable<Triple<T>>
```

There is of course the inline compare with Collections.sort(comparable) if you don't want to commit to what T is.

That should get you started.  Post back/edit if you get stuck.
Cheers.

(And this is not a solution by intent).  Generics are a pain and need to be slogged through to get good at.

Comment: `Triple` should not implement `Comparable` interface. The assignment is for class `ComparableTriple` to do so, so the `Triple` class doesn't have that restriction.

Comment: Yeah, and I said that it wasn't a solution by intent.

Comment: Down-vote is for the misdirected talk about some other type, e.g. `Number`. The assignment is for `class ComparableTriple<T extends Compable<T>> extends Triple<T> implements Compable<ComparableTriple<T>>`. There is no introduction of any specific other type.

Comment: and how would you interpret this? Write a parameterized class Triple that represents a **trio of some type (eg, the Three of String, the Integer , etc.)**. Number is a subclass of "sometype" last I checked.  But I think I'll just quit this site because the user-base is the cancer of learning.

Comment: I interpreted it exactly the way OP did: `Triple<T>`. Where `T` can be "some type".